# SOLVED / Cannot partially or fully edit a contact profile - Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception / after 4.7.10 upgrade

Tags: wordpress, error, core

SOLVED by enabling OpenSSL support in PHP.ini file (remove ";" in front of the "extension=php_openssl.dll" line)

After upgrading to 4.7.10 (Wordpress 4.6), I receive an error when saving changes to a contact profile (the address in my case). Please find below the details, any quick help will be much appreciated as we're blocked right now with this issue.
Thanks

> BACKTRACE
>
> ## 0 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php(182):
>
> CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
>
> ## 1 internal function: CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(PEAR_Error))
>
> ## 2 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(931):
>
> call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
>
> ## 3 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(566):
>
> PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("Need PHP 4.3.0 or later with OpenSSL support
>   for https:// requests", 2, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
>
> ## 4 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTTP\Request.php(703):
>
> PEAR->raiseError("Need PHP 4.3.0 or later with OpenSSL support for
>   https:// requests", 2)
>
> ## 5 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Geocode\Google.php(126):
>
> HTTP_Request->sendRequest()
>
> ## 6 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\Address.php(387):
>
> CRM_Utils_Geocode_Google::format((Array:21))
>
> ## 7 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\Address.php(144):
>
> CRM_Core_BAO_Address::fixAddress((Array:21))
>
> ## 8 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\Address.php(120):
>
> CRM_Core_BAO_Address::add((Array:21), TRUE)
>
> ## 9 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\Location.php(69):
>
> CRM_Core_BAO_Address::create((Array:83), TRUE, NULL)
>
> ## 10 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Contact.php(348):
>
> CRM_Core_BAO_Location::create((Array:83), TRUE)
>
> ## 11 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\Form\Contact.php(986):
>
> CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create((Array:83), TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
>
> ## 12 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Form.php(423):
>
> CRM_Contact_Form_Contact->postProcess()
>
> ## 13 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Upload.php(166):
>
> CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
>
> ## 14 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Upload.php(133):
>
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact),
>   "upload")
>
> ## 15 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Controller.php(203):
>
> CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact),
>   "upload")
>
> ## 16 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Page.php(103):
>
> HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Contact),
>   "upload")
>
> ## 17 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Controller.php(351):
>
> HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
>
> ## 18 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Wrapper.php(113):
>
> CRM_Core_Controller->run()
>
> ## 19 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(286):
>
> CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Contact", "Nouveau contact",
>   (Array:1))
>
> ## 20 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(86):
>
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
>
> ## 21 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(54):
>
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
>
> ## 22 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
>
> ## 23 internal function: CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
>
> ## 24 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-includes\plugin.php(524): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
>
> ## 25 D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-admin\admin.php(222): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
>
> ## 26 {main}
>
> Désolé, nous ne sommes pas en mesure de fournir ceci actuellement.
>   Need PHP 4.3.0 or later with OpenSSL support for https:// requests
>   Message d'erreur détaillé Détails additionnels :
>
> Array (
>       [callback] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => CRM_Core_Error
>               [1] => handle
>           )
>
> ```
> [code] => 2
> [message] => Need PHP 4.3.0 or later with OpenSSL support for https:// requests
> [mode] => 16
> [debug_info] => 
> [type] => PEAR_Error
> [user_info] => 
> [to_string] => [pear_error: message="Need PHP 4.3.0 or later with OpenSSL support for https:// requests" code=2 mode=callback
> ```
>
> callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=""] )
>
> Retourner à la page d'accueil.
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity
>   error: Expected to find active frame thrown in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\gdc\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\Civi\Core\Transaction\Manager.php
>   on line 107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> Need PHP 4.3.0 or later with OpenSSL support for https:// requests

What PHP version are you using? [CiviCRM PHP Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements) are currently:

> PHP 5.5 or greater is recommended, but not PHP7 yet (see CRM-17789:
>   Support PHP 7 ). PHP 5.3.10 is the bare minimum.

This might help re OpenSSL support: [Enabling the openssl in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466086/enabling-the-openssl-in-xampp).

From the backtrace, the https request appears to relate to Google geocoding, so as a workaround you could try disabling that to get yourself up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. We're using PHP Version 5.6.15. I activated the OpenSSL support and it works ! Thanks very much

Comment: Great, glad this helped! If this solved your problem, Stack Exchange etiquette is to upvote and accept the answer. This lets people see that the question has been answered; it also improves CiviCRM Stack Exchange's statistics, helping us to get out of beta.